# Sendgrid sends email with 4 minute dela

Tags: email, gmail, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

We have a trouble with sending first email to user. For example:

We send email to user at 10:10am, but user will get this email after 4 minutes (10:14am) and the time of receiving mail is showing 10:10am. But it happens only on first email, second one user will get without delay (maybe this delay will appear again after few days, I'm not sure).

I have analyzed email headers using google admin toolbox and that's what I got:
[image: This Screenshot] contains email headers for delayed email

Email without delay is almost the same, but does not have last row with 4 min delay.

I contacted sendgrid support - they said that sendrigd sends email in 1-2 seconds (first row in table on screenshot) and they received Ok response from gmail in 2 seconds.

Do you have any ideas why this delay can happen?

Comment: One area I suspect is email explorer you are using could delay the display of received email. My experience is that sendgrid indeed sends emails under a second but my outlook client sometimes takes 10 secs to flash the received email on my desktop but mobile device shows it pretty much under a sec or two.

Comment: One more place to investigate is your own email provider which is probably Gmail in your case.